# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError even though LD_LIBRARY_PATH and -Djava.library.path were set

Tags: java, matlab, java-native-interface, matlab-compiler

OS is Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

(The application runs absolutely fine on Windows, I did not have to configure anything after the installation of Matlab Compiler SDK)

I am writing a web application in Java which also calls some functions written in Matlab which requires install Matlab Compiler SDK, after the installation, it told me to append this `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/sys/os/glnxa64:` to the end of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, which I did by

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/sys/os/glnxa64:
```

But why do I keep getting this error when I try to run the web app in Netbeans?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the required library libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.0.1 on java.library.path.
This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MCR. Its absence may indicate an issue with that installation or the current path configuration.
```

`libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.0.1` resides inside the `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64` directory

I also added `-Djava.library.path` to point to 3 directory entries above to see if it helps, but it does not do anything good at all.

I read several posts on here, but did not seem to solve it.

1. [JNI: Library is Found on Path, but Method is not (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367700/jni-library-is-found-on-path-but-method-is-not-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror?rq=1)
2. [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError even on setting -Djava.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203075/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-even-on-setting-djava-library-path)

How do I fix this? BTW, this is a web application

Comment: Can you verify that you've set `java.library.path` correctly? What is the value of `java.library.path` property if you run `java -Djava.library.path=<your paths> -XshowSettings:properties`?

Comment: @vsminkov It just returns whatever I passed which is `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/sys/os/glnxa64:`

Comment: so... In `showSettings` output path doesn't split on `:`? What is `path.separator` then?

Comment: `path.separator` is `:`, it does split on `:` since this is Linux, `java.library.path` showed `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_‌​Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/sys/os/glnxa64:` without the colon `:`

Comment: that sounds strange. is there any chance that there is mess with 64/32-bit libraries?

Comment: Yeah, it has been annoying me for awhile, only happens on my Linux, on Windows, it runs just fine. Here is the link to the SDK http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/

Comment: inside java how do you load the link library?

Comment: What does `ldd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64/libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.0.1` say?

Comment: @Dummy did you find a solution to this? For sometimes it finds it and sometimes it fails with the error you mentioned.

Comment: @Jay so we decided to roll with windows because we didn't want to deal with the trouble, but I think you could try exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then starts your IDE from the command line using the same terminal, that way, the terminal session in which you exported the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is preserved . I am not sure if this will work because I haven't tried.

Comment: @Dummy I also did the same, couldn't figure it out how to get it working on Ubuntu. Tried couple of things... 
1.) set matlab.conf and added it under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` - This screwed up my system wide `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, 
2.) set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` under by `.bashrc`, this also didnt help,
3.) set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` under the `idea.vmoptions`, didnt help.

Seems some issue with MCR on linux, or the right configuration is not documented on mathworks site.

Comment: @Jay, not sure if it is still relevant to you, but I managed to fix it on a MacOS. Should be similar for Linux

Comment: @Dummy not relevant any more, but anyway, thanks for getting back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ Tested on Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.5 (17F77), should be similar for Linux ]

What I did was when I started the application server (In my case Payara). I provided the path to the `javabuilder.jar` like so

For Payara Full

`asadmin deploy --libraries /path/to/javabuilder.jar app.war`

For Payara Micro

`java -jar payara-micro.jar --deploy app.war --addlibs /path/to/javabuilder.jar`

**Note**:
`/path/to/javabuilder.jar` is the location of `javabuilder.jar` within the directory `MATLAB_HOME/MATLAB_Runtime/SOME_VERSION/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar`, Copying this `javabuilder.jar` file out and reference it will fail with the same error. It **must** be its original path for it to work. Not sure why